# Adpter to Adpter communication Android RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, kotlin, interface, android-recyclerview

I have two recyclerview AParent and AChild, where Aparent is the outer recyclerview and Achild is an item inside AParent(recyclerview inside recyclerview ). I cannot figure out how to communicate to call a function or update AParent from Achild.

```
Parent Recyclerview : AParent
Parent RecyclerAdapter :AParentAdapter

Child Recyclerview: AChild
child RecyclerviewAdapter: AChildAdapter
```

> make a call from AchildAdapter to AParentAdapter,

Is there any best way to communicate recycler adapter to recycler adapter?

Comment: sorry I don't get, new to kotlin, Plase add some link or description will helpful even for java

Comment: Are you sure that you cannot do your code with 1 level of `RecyclerView` and different types? As far as I know, it is not a good idea idea to put scrolling view inside each other.

Comment: @Afshin I have a single horizontal  recycler view  and have a horizontal scroll list item

Comment: @SubinBabu you mean you have 1 horizontal recyclerview inside another horizontal one as its item?If so, you may be able to use 1 scroll recyclerview for both parent and child with 1 adapter for all of your data. RecyclerView is a great widget and I never need to place it inside another scrolling view unless I have no control over it.

Comment: @Afshin how to put list item as a child of parent recyclerview without put a list or recycler into parent recycler. Can any custom method do that

Comment: @SubinBabu don't put list item as child. just add its items into parent recycler as a different item type(with different layout if it is).Then you will have just 1 recycler which handles both.

Comment: @Afshin any link or tutorial will helpful

Comment: @SubinBabu you can find several in internet like https://medium.com/@gilbertchristopher/a-recyclerview-with-multiple-view-type-22619a5ad365 and https://android.jlelse.eu/a-recyclerview-with-multiple-item-types-dfba3979050 .I don't guarantee it works for you, but I think it should.

Comment: @Afshin Thanks...